# Convert CHAR column to DATETIME column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table 'day_trade' with a CHAR column named 'date' with data in this format:
Thu Apr 26 2018 00:00:22 GMT+0000

I want to covert this column to a DATETIME so I can performance data conversions, etc. on the column.  I've been using str_to_date function but it's not always reliable.

I can run the following SQL and get the data out in the date format I want

```
select convert(str_to_date(date, "%a %b %d %Y %k:%i:%s"),datetime) from alert_test.day_trade
```

2018-04-26 00:00:22

So with that I tried running the following statement:

```
update alert_test.day_trade set date = convert(str_to_date(date, "%a %b %d %Y %k:%i:%s"),datetime)
```

Plan was to covert the string into a valid DATETIME format then perform an alter on the column to DATETIME type

```
0   78  13:17:51    update alert_test.day_trade set date = convert(str_to_date(date, "%a %b %d %Y %k:%i:%s"),datetime)  Error Code: 1292.
```

I get the following error:

```
Truncated incorrect datetime value: 'Thu Apr 26 2018 00:00:22 GMT+0000' 0.047 sec
```

I then thought to create a new 'date2' column of type DATETIME and tried selecting from date, converting and inserting into date2:

```
update alert_test.day_trade set date2 = convert(str_to_date(date, "%a %b %d %Y %k:%i:%s"),datetime)
```

same error

Lastly I created a date3 for type VARCHAR and thought I'll do the conversion into date3 then either a) alter that column to DATETIME or do a select insert into date2 which is already a DATETIME.

```
update alert_test.day_trade set date3 = convert(str_to_date(date, "%a %b %d %Y %k:%i:%s"),datetime)
```

same error.

Basically I'm unable to convert my data into a valid DATETIME format.

Comment: You should strip off the time zone information before conversion.

Comment: 2nd vote on the truncation. Probably can do the same with the leading day value too. Should be way easier.

Answer (score 0):

> *I have a table 'day_trade' with a CHAR column named 'date' with data in this format: Thu Apr 26 2018 00:00:22 GMT+0000*
>
> `str_to_date(date, "%a %b %d %Y %k:%i:%s")`
>
> `Truncated incorrect datetime value: 'Thu Apr 26 2018 00:00:22 GMT+0000'`

You're missing a bit, the time zone and offset.

```
str_to_date(date, "%a %b %d %Y %k:%i:%s GMT+0000")
```

If you're lucky and all your datetimes are in GMT, you're done.

If not, that's a whole other question.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed after posting the GMT was causing the issue.  I didn't need that information so I just removed it then conversion worked as expected.

```
update alert_test.day_trade set date = replace(date," GMT+0000", "")
```